# Simple graphs (without parallel edges) in fgl?

Tags: haskell

Are there any provisions in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl for handling simple graphs (i.e., no parallel edges)? At the moment, we get

```
import Data.Graph.Inductive
mkGraph [(1,()),(2,())] [(1,2,()),(1,2,())] :: Gr () ()

==>  mkGraph [(1,()),(2,())] [(1,2,()),(1,2,())]
```

containing two edges from 1 to 2. Indeed for this graph,

```
suc g 1  ==>  [2,2]
```

Just to show that I've done some research: the official documentation http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/haskell/old/fgl0103.pdf (paper linked from original web page) states in Section 2.1 "we define one type for directed, node-labelled, edge-labelled multi-graphs; other graph types can be obtained as special cases" but then am seeing just the trivial specialisation (no label = label ()), but nothing on simple graphs.

For simple graphs, the type of `Adj b`, which occurs in `Context a b`, should perhaps be `Set (b,Node)` instead of `[(b,Node)]` as it is now.
(Or even `Map b (Set Node)`, or `Map Node (Set b)` ...)

Somewhat related: is there a method that allows to check for the presence of an edge, or give me the set of edges from one node `p` to another node `q`? At the moment it seems I have to find `q` by walking through `suc g p`. And that's a list, which worries me even more. What if my graph has nodes with large degree?